# Xcode 5, how to use autolayout with orientation, in the shown scenario?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, autolayout

I'm struggling with AutoLayout, to arrange two buttons as shown below.
I've watched the initial 2012 WWDC video and the Xcode-5 WWDC update video.
Also various other videos and tutorials.

I'm having trouble describing the issue so I've produced an image to show the problem.

I can align simple layouts, like two buttons at the bottom of the screen and I've tried adding a container then adding the buttons to that.

I'm beginning to think this might not be possible.

Can someone advise?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seem like common behaviors that we might ask Auto Layout to perform:

- move the top half of a layout in portrait to the left half in landscape
- **and**, move the bottom half of a layout in portrait to the right half in landscape

Here's how I would do it. I would create two content views for the two halves of the layout. Although the content views would be created in IB, all of their constraints would merely be placeholders and removed at runtime (by checking a box in each constraint's `Attributes` inspector). In order to create placeholder constraints, however, you need to create constraints explicitly in IB. In code, the constraints for the content views are created dynamically in response to device rotation.

[image]

The advantage to this approach is that you can layout the subviews for the content views in IB and not have to worry about orientation. The configuration of the content views' constraints could be abstracted out into a `UIViewController` base class.

Here's a screenshot of the content views without any subviews. The root view is white and can be seen peaking behind the status bar.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code for configuring the content views' constraints:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topContentView; // moves to the left half in landscape
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bottomContentView; // moves to the right half in landscape
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *constraintsForContentViews;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.constraintsForContentViews = @[];

    [self configureConstraintsForContentViewsForInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
}

// instead of creating this helper method, this code could be placed in the view controller's updateViewConstraints method
- (void)configureConstraintsForContentViewsForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    UIView *topView = self.topContentView;
    UIView *bottomView = self.bottomContentView;
    UIView *leftView = self.topContentView; // unnecessary but improves readibility of visual format
    UIView *rightView = self.bottomContentView; // unnecessary but improves readibility of visual format
    id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
    id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;
    NSArray *visualFormats = nil;

    // remove prior constraints
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.constraintsForContentViews];
    self.constraintsForContentViews = @[];

    // build visual formats for orientation
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {

        // portrait
        visualFormats = @[@"H:|[topView]|", @"H:|[bottomView]|", @"V:[topGuide][topView(bottomView)][bottomView(topView)][bottomGuide]"];

    } else {

        // landscape: topView becomes leftView by name only, bottomView becomes rightView by name only
        visualFormats = @[@"H:|[leftView(rightView)][rightView(leftView)]|", @"V:[topGuide][leftView][bottomGuide]", @"V:[topGuide][rightView][bottomGuide]"];
    }

    // install new constraints
    for (NSString *format in visualFormats) {

        NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(topView, bottomView, leftView, rightView, topGuide, bottomGuide)];
        [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

        self.constraintsForContentViews = [self.constraintsForContentViews arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:constraints];
    }
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self configureConstraintsForContentViewsForInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

@end
```

Comment: Wow that seems like a lot of code.. I'm getting an error ... Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints… Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)… NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint… IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V….

Comment: Explicitly create constraints in IB so you can check the box in their Attributes inspector which removes them at runtime. Prototyping constraints will automatically go away when you explicitly create constraints in IB.

Comment: @bilobatum: this is an absolutely brilliant post. Worked fine here and I think it is an elegant way to do this "pattern"

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've been doing is, on your "left pane", add top and left constraints, then height and width. On the "right pane", add bottom and right constraints, height and width.

Then on `- willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` you can adjust each constraint's constant to make the sizes exactly what you want.

Comment: The ideal solution would be IB allow you to place the elements in both orientations, but it is not possible. Setting the frame (x, y, width, height) is sort of exhausting and complicated. Autolayout makes things a little less terrible. This mix of autolayout and code is what I found to be the best effectiveness/effort ratio.

Comment: So using the orientation event, can I transcribe the constraints into code? Is that visual format language ?

Comment: You can define the constraints in your Storyboard and change their values with code. Or you can set all of them on code. Visual Format Language is one way to do that, but not the only one.